# How do I use PHP to build a website menu with dynamic highlighting?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to change  color of selected menu whenever that page is active and it should stay until another menu is clicked.I have used jquery like

```
$('.navigation ul li a').click(function(){

 $(this).css({"background-color":"#ffffff"});
 $('.navigation ul li a').css({"background":"transparent"});
```

});

But it works only  for the click function only.I need it to be active till i move to another menu .plz help!!!

Answer (score 1):

### PHP Only

Let us assume that your website has the following menu:

- Home
- Pistols
- Rifles

At the top of the *Home* HTML page, insert:

```
<?php $this_page = "Home"; ?>
```

At the top of the *Pistols* HTML page, insert:

```
<?php $this_page = "Pistols"; ?>
```

At the top of the *Rifles* HTML page, insert:

```
<?php $this_page = "Rifles"; ?>
```

In your css-file, add an id, with the accompanying format, for the menu item whose page is the one displayed in the browser. Call this id `#cur_item`, for example.

Edit your navigation HTML to look like this:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li <?php if ($this_page == "Home"):?> id="cur_item" <?php endif; ?> >
        Home
    </li>
    <li <?php if ($this_page == "Pistols"):?> id="cur_item" <?php endif; ?> >
        Pistols
    </li>
    <li <?php if ($this_page == "Rifles"):?> id="cur_item" <?php endif; ?> >
        Rifles
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any jQuery, just CSS.

- give your body tag and id for the page i.e. body id="contact"
- give each menu link a class that matches the body id
- Write the CSS for your active links:

'

```
body#home .navigation ul li a.home, 
body#services .navigation ul li a.services,
body#contact .navigation ul li a.contact {
    background-color: #ffffff
}
```

'

Comment: waht you mean by .navigation ul li a.home,  home given as a class or id?

Comment: home is a class on the a tag and an id on the homepage. Here is an article you can read to further understand http://www.search-this.com/2007/06/13/css-current-page-indicator/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use css `a:active` tag for this

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.navigation ul li a').click(function () {

    $('.navigation ul li a').each(function () { // loop through all links
       if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).removeClass('active'); // remove className 'active' from any link
    });

    $(this).addClass('active'); // className active to current link
});
```

**CSS**

```
.navigation ul li a {
    background: transparent;
}

.navigation ul li a.active {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: **@Q_Mlilo**: hi...its me..thanks for ur response..but it only works in click function.i need that link to be highlighted as long as we are on that page.